# Recursive function to convert DNF to negated CNF form

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I am trying to define a **recursive** function

> $g : DNF \rightarrow CNF$

such that for any propositional formula $\varphi$, $g(\varphi)\equiv \neg\varphi$.

I tried to split that into cases, such as follows:

- If $\varphi=p$ then $g(\varphi)=\neg p$     where $p$ is atomic propositional variable
- If $\varphi=\neg p$ then $g(\varphi)=p$     where $p$ is atomic propositional variable
- If $\varphi=\alpha\vee\beta$, then $g(\varphi)=\neg g(\alpha)\wedge\neg g(\beta)$
- If $\varphi=\alpha\wedge\beta$, then $g(\varphi)=\neg g(\alpha)\vee\neg g(\beta)$
- ...

But for the complex binary connective I am not sure the result is actually a *CNF* form of $\neg \varphi$, nor I know how to prove it.

Please help me to define such a function and help me to prove it's correctness.

Please advise. Thank you.

Comment: Just try your proposal out on $(p \land q) \lor r$. You won't get a CNF because, in a CNF (or a DNF), negation is restricted to negation of atoms. To fix this, just delete the $\lnot$s in the clauses for $\lor$ and $\land$ (and get rid of the clause for ..., as there is no other possibility for a DNF input).

Comment: Thanks @RobArthan, did you mean to delete the $\neg$ in the clauses for $\vee$ and $\wedge$?

Comment: Yes - I've fixed the comment.

Comment: So you say that $g(p)=\neg p$   ;   $g(\neg p)=p$   ;   
$g(\alpha\vee\beta)=g(\alpha)\wedge g(\beta)$   ;   $g(\alpha\wedge\beta)=g(\alpha)\vee g(\beta)$ is a correct definition? Any idea how to justify it simply? Thank you very much!

Comment: I have written up an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix your definition just by removing the negations from the clauses for $\alpha \lor \beta$ and $\alpha \land \beta$. If you define:
$$
\begin{align*}
g(p) &= \lnot p \\
g(\lnot p) &= p\\
g(\alpha \lor \beta) &= g(\alpha) \land g(\beta) \\
g(\alpha \land \beta) &= g(\alpha) \lor g(\beta) \\
\end{align*}
$$
where $p$ denotes an atom and $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are any formulas. Then (1) $g(\phi)$ is well-defined for any $\phi$ that is in DNF (because in a DNF negations only occur in literals) and (2) $g(\phi) \equiv \lnot \phi$, for any $\phi$ in DNF, which you can prove by induction on the size of the DNF formula $\phi$: it is clear in the base cases, when $\phi$ is $p$ or $\lnot p$, and in the inductive steps, if $g(\alpha) \equiv \lnot\alpha$ and $g(\beta) \equiv \lnot \beta$, then you have:
$$
g(\alpha \lor \beta) = g(\alpha) \land g(\beta) \equiv \lnot \alpha \land \lnot\beta \equiv \lnot(\alpha \lor \beta)
$$
and similarly for $g(\alpha \land \beta)$.

Comment: Thank you very much!